# Select attribute and text() in the same query

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I would like to select a attribute and the text() value of a node in one query, e.g. I have

```
<Tag1 @myattr='test'>MyText</Tag1>
```

and I am interested in getting "test" and "MyText" with one query.

The obvious

```
//Tag1/@myattr | //Tag1/text()
```

fails due to the fact, that Unions are only allowed over node-sets.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think, given XPath 2.0, you want a sequence of string values which you get with `//Tag1/(@myattr, .)/string()`. If you want a single string then use `//Tag1/string-join((@myattr, .), ' ')`.

BTW, your path `//Tag1/@myattr | //Tag1/text()` would select a sequence containing an attribute value and a text node. I don't see how that would fail.

Comment: I am using jaxen and the query **//Tag1/string-join((@myattr, .), ' ')** fails due to "Expected node-type" and the query **//Tag1/(@myattr, .)/string()** due to "Expected one of '.', '..', '@', '*', <QName>"

Comment: Are you sure you use an engine like Saxon 9 that supports XPath 2.0? Or why did you tag the question as `xpath-2.0`? Even with XPath 1.0 you should be able to evaluate your path `//Tag1/@myattr | //Tag1/text()`, giving you a node set of an attribute node and a text node. My suggestions are XPath 2.0 only.

Comment: Well, infact Saxen only supports XPATH 1.0. Sorry for the confusion. However, I can't figur out why my path `//Tag1/@myattr | //Tag1/text()`fails. Maybe it is an internal problem of Saxen...!?

Comment: What is "Saxen"? I only know "Saxon" it exists as Saxon 6.5.5 doing XSLT and XPath 1.0 and Saxon 9.5 doing XSLT and XPath 2.0 (and XQuery 1.0). If `//Tag1/@myattr | //Tag1/text()` fails then tell us the exact failure message if you need help with that and the steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: OMG, it is time for a break for me... Did I write Saxen? I mean jaxen.... (v1.1.6). Sorry!